# GraphQL Error : Must provide name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, express-graphql

I am writing mutation for logging in user in NodeJS.

It is giving error "Must Provide Name".

Here is Browser GraphQL Query:

```
mutation{
  login(username:"dfgdfg",password:"test1234") {
    _id,
    name{
      fname,
      lname,
      mname
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code

```
    const login = {
    type: UserType,
    args: {
        input:{
            name:'Input',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLObjectType(
                {
                    username:{
                    name:'Username',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                    },
                    password:{
                    name:'Password',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                    }
                }
            ))

        }
    },
    resolve: async (_, input, context) => {
        let errors = [];
        return UserModel.findById("5b5c34a52092182f26e92a0b").exec();

    }
  }

module.exports = login;
```

Could anyone please help me out why it is giving error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your mutation or the query from the browser

Comment: I updated the question and put graphQL browser mutation query. Please check.

Comment: try to pass `name` in input parameter not in mutation `login` function parameter and mutation should be like this `mutation{
  login(input: $input) {
    _id,
    name{
      fname,
      lname,
      mname
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is also very helpful to describe *where* the error occurs. I assume it is thrown when you start the node server.

This specific error is thrown because you are missing the `name` property in line 8 of the object config. Also this type needs to be `GraphQLInputObjectType`not `GraphQLObjectType`.

```
args: {
    input: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLInputObjectType({
            name: 'LoginInput',
            fields: {
                username:{
                    name:'Username',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                },
                password:{
                    name:'Password',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                }
            }
        }))
    }
},
```

**There are a bunch of more problems in your code:**

All the `name` properties are not used in your code (you probably added them trying to fix the error).

Your query mismatches the schema definition, either have the two args `username` and `password` directly on the field instead of in an extra input type:

```
args: {
    username:{
        name:'Username',
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    },
    password:{
        name:'Password',
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    }
},
```

Or adopt your query as described by Anthony:

```
mutation{
  login(input: { username: "dfgdfg",password: "test1234" }) {
    _id,
    name{
      fname,
      lname,
      mname
    }
  }
}
```